# Numpy busday_offset error: REFS_OK flat was not enable

Tags: pandas, numpy

When applying `numpy.busday_offset` to `pandas.DateTimeIndex`, I got the `RERS_OK flag` error as below. May I ask how to address this issue?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(['2008-01-01', '2008-01-02']).date
>> array([datetime.date(2008, 1, 1), datetime.date(2008, 1, 2)], dtype=object)

np.busday_offset(pd.to_datetime(['2008-01-01', '2008-01-02']).date, 0)
>> TypeError: Iterator operand or requested dtype holds references, but the REFS_OK flag was not enabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your source array as:

```
arr = np.arange(np.datetime64('2008-01-01'), np.datetime64('2008-01-03'))
```

The result is:

```
array(['2008-01-01', '2008-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

An important detail is that the resolution of the date in this case is "D" (day).

Then you can run `np.busday_offset(arr, 0)` getting:

```
array(['2008-01-02', '2008-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Or if you have  a non-continuous series of dates, proceed as follows:

1. Create a list of string representation of dates of your choice, e.g.:

   ```
   a = ['2008-01-01', '2008-01-02', '2008-01-07']
   ```
2. Convert it to *np.datetime64* type:

   ```
   arr = [ np.datetime64(it) for it in a ]
   ```
3. Then you can run `np.busday_offset(arr, 0)` getting:

   ```
   array(['2008-01-01', '2008-01-02', '2008-01-07'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
   ```